# Sharepoint 2010 and JQuery - hiding a field based on multiple selection choices

Tags: jquery, checkbox, sharepoint

I will preface this by saying that I've figured out how to make this work for simple yes/no checkboxes and for dropdown lists, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to fetch the value for multiple selection checkboxes. I've tried it in InfoPath too, to no avail; it doesn't seem to want to work with multiple checkboxes selected.

I have a List with a Choice column. This column has 3 checkboxes, of which multiple selections are able to be made.

```
Column A - Choice1, Choice2, Choice3.
```

I want to hide Column B (a text box, for example) by default, and if Choice1 is selected, Column B shows up. If choice 1 and choice2 are both selected, then Column C (a different control) appears.

I can't get it to return the right value, and I recognize there's 8 cases I have to account for: nothing, all, 1 choice (3 of them), 2 choices (3 of them). All I'm requesting is how I would go about coding the one case that will be successful; I can extrapolate the other cases.

My code for the dropdown box is as follows, and works as intended:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type=text/javascript></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Execute the following JavaScript after the page has fully loaded, when it's ".ready"

$(document).ready(function(){

 //Define which columns to show/hide by default

  $('nobr:contains("ColumnB")').parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').hide();
  $('nobr:contains("ColumnC")').parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').hide();
  $('nobr:contains("ColumnD")').parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').hide();

 //Show/hide columns based on Drop Down Selection  

 $("select[title='ColumnA]").change(function() {

  if ($("select[title='ColumnA']").val() == "Choice1") { 

  $('nobr:contains("ColumnB")').parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').show();

  } else if($("select[title='ColumnA]").val() == "Choice1" && "Choice2"){ 

  $('nobr:contains("ColumnB")').parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').hide();

  $('nobr:contains("ColumnC")').parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').show();

  } 

 });


});
```